# oF: error C2039: '_Dynamic_tag' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I've just started using openFrameworks and am using the 0072 Visual Studio version. When I tried to build the empty sample project oF provided me with, it gave me only this error:

error C2039: '_Dynamic_tag' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and seemingly this issue has already been solved, but in VS2010 version, [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/pull/1341).

I've checked the ofTypes.h with the solved one and there was not a difference.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that VS2012 takes `std::tr1::` out entirely in favour of having the new C++11 features in `std::`, though you may be able to put it back with some compiler option.

If nothing else, it looks like OFW is using internal, implementation variables (the leading underscore is a clue), which was a pretty silly thing to do.

The implication then would be that [OpenFrameWorks needs another update](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=10758.0).

Comment: So you mean the syntax for C++ has changed?

Comment: @GreekFellows: Oh, the `std::tr1` namespace was like a temporary holding place for features that were coming up. Now, and as supported in VS2012 (partially), they are part of the official C++ language (per C++11 - yes the syntax has changed, though this is not really about syntax) and therefore would be moved and/or copied to the base `std::` namespace. The specifics of how when and why you can still use `std::tr1::` in VS2012 are beyond me but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: When I changed the `std::tr1::`s to `std::` they seem to have worked. Thanks!